# table with fixed column not rendering correctly

Tags: antd

Please see the link below for an example of the problem. The first column is fixed, the second column is not. Between the first and the second column, there is what looks like a massive empty column. I'm not sure why this is happening, I'm hoping someone will be able to clarify.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-sky-xihjm

This is a stripped down version of my code when I am letting the user dynamically add/remove columns, with the first column preset and is fixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You giving the `Age` column a fixed `width` of `100`, it won't dynamically disappear when goes to `fixed` mode.

Give it a lesser `width`, although it should be responsive it solves the problem.

```
  {
    title: 'Age',
    width: 50,
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
    fixed: 'left',
  },
```

Comment: Dennis, that didn't resolve the issue. See https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-sky-xihjm.